# html5 : how to prevent pause button when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a
`<video controls>` element

When I click on the video (inside the video content), video pauses (Chrome). Is there a way to prevent that (but I still need controls be enabled) ?
So solution like:

```
 pointer-events: none;
```

will not work for me (User should be able to pause the video clicking on play / pause control button), but not clicking inside the video

Answer (score 0):

Add a click eventhandler to the given video and call preventDefault.

```js
document.querySelector('video').addEventListener('click', (e) => e.preventDefault() )
```

The control will still work, but clicking on the video will not play/pause it.

Comment: No. Because that will prevent also clicking on controls.

Comment: it seems it is browser dependent:  https://codepen.io/ste-xx/pen/popPYBK this works on chrome v99, MacOs (does not block controls). On firefox, this does nothing (video is played after clicking. controls are not blocked). At least with the default html5 video element. do you use videojs?